# How do I fix this memory leak in c

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I have to create a function allocate all memory needed, read in data, and create linked list accordingly.
there is a memory leak happens at A= malloc(sizeof(Order)); It works well but give me a memory leak. can anyone help?

```
typedef struct o_
{
    int ID; //the order number
    int daysInQueue; //the number of days old the order is
    struct o_* nextOrder; //to the next order in the list
} Order;


Order** importLists(char* filename)
{
    FILE *fptr = fopen(filename,"r");
    Order ** b = malloc(sizeof(Order*)*4);

    int i;
    for ( i=0; i< 4; i++)
    {
        b[i]=NULL;
    }
    Order* A;
    while (A != NULL)
    {
        A = malloc(sizeof(Order));
        fscanf(fptr,"%d%d%d", &A ->ID, &A -> daysInQueue, &i );
        if (feof(fptr))
        {
            break;
        }
        A-> nextOrder = b[i];
        b[i]=A;

    }
    fclose(fptr);

    return b;
}
```

Comment: You need to post your complete code if you want to know how to fix the problem.

Comment: Note that `Order *A; while (A != NULL)` is pretty suspicious, since it is very well possible that `A` is `NULL` when it is declared. I would rather use a `do`-`while` loop instead, or an infinite loop (`while (TRUE)`) and a `break`.

Comment: thanks. I did in that way and get rid of 32 bytes, and there is still 16 bytes left which is one Node memory leak.

Comment: Nvm, I add free(A) inside the feof function which frees the space. thx again

Answer (score 1):

You only need to allocate memory to A when you instante it.

`Order * A = (Order *)malloc(sizeof(Order));`

The `(Order *)` before `malloc(...)` is a cast to type Order*, because malloc returns void* type.

In your `while` loop you're allocating memory to A indefinitely *(while A!= NULL)*, this is why you got a memory leak.

Tip (cause I think here is not the right place to explain it):You should read more about malloc() and free() functions. You maybe find it useful, cause you probably also need to modify the declaration of you `Order **b` and/or re-thinking parts of your algorithim (I didn't test it, sorry x)).